# Цитаты с "или" как однородные подлежащие

Tags: пунктуация, кавычки, цитата

Конструкция:

> "Съешьте пряник" или "съешьте камень" звучит для меня одинаково
>   непривлекательно.

Я нахожу, что если цитата выступает как часть придаточного или дополнение, то можно писать её с маленькой буквы. А тут как? С одной стороны, вроде бы это как часть предложения, заглавная буква не просится. С другой стороны, я не могу найти подтверждения своей мысли.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Здесь цитируется не предложение, а фраза, или даже просто два слова. Это подобно фрагменту предложения. Поэтому заглавная буква в середине предложения не нужна.

Comment: А если длинная фраза? Когда цитата, например, выступает в роли определения или сложного подлежащего. Например:
«Иначе получится привычное "Сама натворила – сама разгребай"».

Comment: Я бы и тут не ставил. Смотрится плохо. Получается вот такой эффект (а не именно такое предложение с большой буквы). Другое дело, если в цитате несколько предложений. Если нужна большая буква, то обычно ставят двоеточие.